# Should we have a [bias-variance] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

The bias-variance tradeoff is a specific topic that isn't quite the same as bias or variance (although they obviously overlap).  It seems like questions about it are thus somewhat distinct.  I wonder if it would be better to have a specific tag to group these questions.  At present, we have [124 threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias+variance) with both tags and another 15 that have only one of the tags plus the word "tradeoff".  This implies we may have something like 140 threads on this topic (compared to 634 threads with [bias](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias) and 2374 with [variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variance)).

Comment: I don't feel strongly about it but if you want to create this tag (and put it on the most prominent threads) then I'd ceratinly have nothing against. I would only suggest to call it more explicitly, e.g. [bias-variance-tradeoff].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no meaningful opposition to this, I'm going to go ahead and create a [bias-variance-tradeoff](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bias-variance-tradeoff) tag and begin the process of retagging.